# JavaScript loop table not placed right

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a calender but the daynames on top arent quite where they should be. the sunday box "sun" keep floating on the top left, i'd like to have it next to the other days (on the left of monday)

```js
    var dayNames = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
    var monthNames = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
    var monthLength = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
    var today = new Date();
    var dag = today.getDay();
    var myMonth = today.getMonth();
    var jaar = today.getFullYear();
    var volBtn = document.getElementById('Volgende');
    var vorBtn = document.getElementById('Vorige');

    function Kalender() {
      var myHTML = '';

      myHTML += '<div id="month">' + monthNames[myMonth] + " " + jaar + '</div><table id="cal">';
      for (var i = 0; i < dayNames.length; i++) {
        myHTML += '<td>' + dayNames[i] + ' ' + '</td>';
        if (i % 6 == 0) {
          myHTML += "</tr>";
        }
      };
      for (var i = 1; i <= monthLength[myMonth]; i++) {
        myHTML += "<td><a href='#'>" + i + "</a></td> ";

        if (i % 7 == 0) {
          myHTML += "</tr>";
        }
      }
      myHTML += '</table>';

      document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = myHTML;
    }

    var VolgendeFunc = function() {
      myMonth = myMonth + 1;

      if (myMonth == 11) {
        volBtn.disabled = true;
        vorBtn.disabled = false;
      } else {
        vorBtn.disabled = false;
        volBtn.disabled = false;
      }

      document.getElementById('month').innerHTML = myMonth;
      Kalender();
    }
    var VorigeFunc = function() {
      myMonth = myMonth - 1;

      if (myMonth == 0) {
        vorBtn.disabled = true;
        volBtn.disabled = false;
      } else {
        vorBtn.disabled = false;
        volBtn.disabled = false;
      }

      document.getElementById('month').innerHTML = myMonth;
      Kalender();
    }

    Kalender();
```

```css
    #div {
      font-size: 19px;
    }
    #div tr {
      color: #2b2b2b;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      line-height: 30px;
      text-align: center;
      border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
      cursor: default;
    }
    #cal {
      font-size: 30px;
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
      margin: 50px auto;
      font: "Helvetica Neue";
      display: table;
    }
    #cal td {
      color: #2b2b2b;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      line-height: 30px;
      text-align: center;
      border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
      cursor: default;
    }
```

```html
<center>
  <button id="Vorige" onclick="VorigeFunc()">Vorige</button>
  <button id="Volgende" onclick="VolgendeFunc()">Volgende</button>
  <div id="div">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Kal.js">
    </script>

  </div>
</center>
```

Comment: why is the link tag not in the head?

Comment: Whoops, fixed. thanks epascarello

Comment: Looks like your code is not calculating rows correctly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your `for` loops are different, this is causing the offset of 'Sun':

```
for (var i = 0; i < dayNames.length; i++){
    myHTML += '<td>' + dayNames[i] + ' ' + '</td>';
    if (i%6 == 0){
        myHTML += "</tr>";
    } 
};
for (var i=1; i <= monthLength[myMonth]; i++){
    myHTML+="<td><a href='#'>" + i + "</a></td> ";

    if (i%7 == 0){
        myHTML += "</tr>";
    } 
}
```

Change them to:

```
for (var i = 0; i < dayNames.length; i++){
    myHTML += '<td>' + dayNames[i] + ' ' + '</td>';
    if ((i+1)%7 == 0){
        myHTML += "</tr>";
    } 
};
for (var i = 0; i < monthLength[myMonth]; i++){
    myHTML+="<td><a href='#'>" + (i + 1) + "</a></td> ";

    if ((i+1)%7 == 0){
        myHTML += "</tr>";
    } 
}
```

should resolve your issue: http://jsfiddle.net/166ea9n9/

Comment: OP didn't ask for the bad markup to be fixed - OP asked for 'Sun' to line up with the other days of the week.

Answer (score 0):

You never add an opening `<tr>` tag for your rows you only close them.

```js
    var dayNames = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
    var monthNames = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
    var monthLength = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
    var today = new Date();
    var dag = today.getDay();
    var myMonth = today.getMonth();
    var jaar = today.getFullYear();
    var volBtn = document.getElementById('Volgende');
    var vorBtn = document.getElementById('Vorige');

    function Kalender() {
      var myHTML = '';

      myHTML += '<div id="month">' + monthNames[myMonth] + " " + jaar + '</div><table id="cal"><thead><tr>';
  

      for (var i = 0; i < dayNames.length; i++) {
        myHTML += '<td>' + dayNames[i] + ' ' + '</td>';
      };
      myHTML += "</tr></thead><tbody>";


      var rows = []
      var row = "";
      for (var i = 1; i <= monthLength[myMonth]; i++) {
        row += "<td><a href='#'>" + i + "</a></td> ";

        if (i % 7 == 0 || i===monthLength[myMonth]) {
          rows.push(row);
          row = "";
        }
      }
 
     myHTML += "<tr>" + rows.join("</tr><tr>") + "</tr>"; 

      myHTML += '</tbody></table>';

      document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = myHTML;
    }

    var VolgendeFunc = function() {
      myMonth = myMonth + 1;

      if (myMonth == 11) {
        volBtn.disabled = true;
        vorBtn.disabled = false;
      } else {
        vorBtn.disabled = false;
        volBtn.disabled = false;
      }

      document.getElementById('month').innerHTML = myMonth;
      Kalender();
    }
    var VorigeFunc = function() {
      myMonth = myMonth - 1;

      if (myMonth == 0) {
        vorBtn.disabled = true;
        volBtn.disabled = false;
      } else {
        vorBtn.disabled = false;
        volBtn.disabled = false;
      }

      document.getElementById('month').innerHTML = myMonth;
      Kalender();
    }

    Kalender();
```

```css
    #div {
      font-size: 19px;
    }
    #div tr {
      color: #2b2b2b;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      line-height: 30px;
      text-align: center;
      border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
      cursor: default;
    }
    #cal {
      font-size: 30px;
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
      margin: 50px auto;
      font: "Helvetica Neue";
      display: table;
    }
    #cal td {
      color: #2b2b2b;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      line-height: 30px;
      text-align: center;
      border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
      cursor: default;
    }
```

```html
<center>
  <button id="Vorige" onclick="VorigeFunc()">Vorige</button>
  <button id="Volgende" onclick="VolgendeFunc()">Volgende</button>
  <div id="div">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Kal.js">
    </script>

  </div>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does changing:

```
  myHTML += '<div id="month">' + monthNames[myMonth] + " " + jaar + '</div><table id="cal">';
      for (var i = 0; i < dayNames.length; i++) {
        myHTML += '<td>' + dayNames[i] + ' ' + '</td>';
        if (i % 6 == 0) {
          myHTML += "</tr>";
        }
      };
```

to:

```
 myHTML += '<div id="month">' + monthNames[myMonth] + " " + jaar + '</div><table id="cal"><tr>';
  for (var i = 0; i < dayNames.length; i++) {
    myHTML += '<td class="yo">' + dayNames[i] + ' ' + '</td>';
  };
  myHTML += '</tr>';
```

work?